# How to access cloudinary attributes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

Given the following output from `f.object.filename.inspect` from a form. And I am using `carrierwave`.

```
$> <CarPhotoUploader:0x007f83efa788f0 
    @model=#<CarPhoto id: 19, filename: "image/upload/v1433056939/eio6d7b0dtfdjptmxud4.png", car_id: 19, document: nil, created_at: "2015-05-31 07:22:04", updated_at: "2015-05-31 07:26:45">, 
    @mounted_as=:filename, 
    @transformation={}, 
    @file=#<Cloudinary::CarrierWave::CloudinaryFile:0x007f83efa786e8 
        @uploader=#<CarPhotoUploader:0x007f83efa788f0 ...>, 
    @identifier="image/upload/v1433056939/eio6d7b0dtfdjptmxud4.png", 
    @resource_type="image", 
    @storage_type="upload", 
    @version="1433056939", 
    @filename="eio6d7b0dtfdjptmxud4.png", 
    @public_id="eio6d7b0dtfdjptmxud4", 
    @format="png">, 
    @stored_public_id="eio6d7b0dtfdjptmxud4", 
    @public_id="eio6d7b0dtfdjptmxud4", 
    @stored_version="1433056939", 
    @original_filename="eio6d7b0dtfdjptmxud4.png">
```

I need to access the `@public_id` but I can't get anything out but `nil` when I do

> f.object.filename.public_id.

What should I do?

Comment: Try `f.object.file.public_id.`

Comment: nope, it returns `undefined method `file' for #<CarPhoto:0x007fcc4ecee358>`.

Comment: well.. what is the output of `f.object.filename.class` ?

Comment: I currently have to use helper method from Carrierwave to get the `f.object.filename.url`. and then parse `url.split('/').last.split('.').first`

Comment: it's `CarPhotoUploader`

Comment: well.. now `puts f.object.filename.class.superclass` ?

Comment: CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `f.object.filename.public_id` gives `nil`.

Because that's how they have implemented. Look at there [source code](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/blob/master/lib/cloudinary/carrier_wave.rb#L71-L74).

What you want is [`my_public_id`](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/blob/master/lib/cloudinary/carrier_wave.rb#L79-L83).

So working code is : `f.object.filename.my_public_id`.

Comment: I believe `f.object.filename.file.public_id` should also work